# MVC - Create, Edit and Detail View with a list

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I'm new to MVC programming, I'm trying to achieve the scenario in a Clinic System. The scenario is this, I have a daily record in which the user encodes data. I was able to produce it in MVC using the scaffolded Index, Edit, Detail and Delete Views. What I want to achieve next is to display the history of a particular record into the Create, Edit and Detail View. The history should be in a list with the same record who has been visiting the clinic.

What I searched so far is that it should be in a Partial View, wherein it should be placed inside a View for example the Edit View. My problem is that I don't know how to achieve that scenario.

Can anybody help please? Any expert with MVC framework?

Comment: Create a `ChildActionOnly()` controller method that generates a partial view of the 'history' (say `public ActionResult History(int ID)`) and then in the view your can use `@Html.Action("History", new { ID = Model.ID })`. And I suspect you don't really want it for a 'Create' view :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you are right, **partial views**  are usefull in these scenarious.

You can load the **partialview** using Jquery Ajax call or any other ajax.

And then load the "**PlaceHolder**" with the partialview rendered by ajax call.

```
$("#viewPlaceHolder").html( <result view [html] of the ajax call>) ;
```

This [link](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/d551d3/how-to-load-partial-views-in-Asp-Net-mvc-using-jquery-ajax/) is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can start by creating a ViewModel for your Record which would contain a collection of RecordHistoryItems. Then you can generate the MVC views via scaffolding or manually and pass on this RecordViewModel.
How and when you want to fetch this list of HistoryItems is up to you.

```
  Public class RecordViewModel
{
  public int RecordId { get; set; }
public string Content { get; set; }
....
public List<RecordHistoryItem> RecordHistory { get; set; }
}
```